# Radgrid string column datatype to add Greater Than

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik, radgrid

I want to add Greater Than in String Type of RadGrid Column in Filter time. If you keep datetime datatype of column then the filter dropdownlist shows "greater than,less than" but when I keep the string datatype then it doesn't show greater than.

I would like to add in the dropdownlist greater than because my requirment to match string greater than [like this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/filtering/defaultcs.aspx)

But I want to add this condition in the dropdown, please can you tell me how to add this to the filter dropdownlist

Comment: i removed the silver-light tag because your sample url is ASP.net Ajax

Comment: what do you mean by String DataType? is it <telerik:GridBoundColumn ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe working with RadGrid1_Init with help of [Reducing the filter menu options](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdreducingfiltermenuoptions.html)  and [Custom option for filtering (FilterListOptions -> VaryByDataTypeAllowCustom)](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdcustomoptionforfiltering.html) solve your problem